# Trying to complete POST with Striga API, HMACs did not match

Tags: php, forms, post, hmac

I'm developing a bank app with Striga API Rest but I can't validate this POST for create a user. Any can help for make this? Thanks!

Output error (On browser):

```
Array ( 
  [authorization] => HMAC 1695284379514:aae87cbddd3f8d87cf78cab03b1d8ac19e9887e718726e3961693904b9722695 
  [api-key] => _U6-ALTe5WWETJdHn8RxIQjUZI-pKW0lmfSTzYPrOhU= 
  [Content-Type] => application/json 
) 

1

POST /api/v1/user/create HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/7 
Host: www.sandbox.striga.com 
authorization: HMAC 1695284379514:aae87cbddd3f8d87cf78cab03b1d8ac19e9887e718726e3961693904b9722695 
api-key: _U6-ALTe5WWETJdHn8RxIQjUZI-pKW0lmfSTzYPrOhU= 
Content-Type: application/json 

{"ping":"pong"}

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Date: Thu, 21 Sep 2023 08:19:39 GMT 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Content-Length: 101 Connection: close 
x-powered-by: Express 
retry-after: 1 
x-ratelimit-reset: Thu Sep 21 2023 08:19:40 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) 
access-control-allow-origin: * 
etag: W/"65-OOJdYmgd11+2jJ4oMcdOGF3LPe4" 
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block 
x-content-type-options: nosniff 
referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade 
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self'; 
permissions-policy: interest-cohort=() 
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload 
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC 
Server: cloudflare 
CF-RAY: 80a0e26c4cd53af9-IAD 
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400 

{"message":"Invalid authentication header","errorCode":"30012","errorDetails":"HMAC's did not match"}
```

POST.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

// VERIFY POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://www.sandbox.striga.com/api/v1/user/create']);
$SANDBOX_API_SECRET = 'dZ+B+XhbpUhqixx2M6UAV3VzpkhGdDqsjYfn41KbaoY=';
$method = 'POST';
$body = ['ping' => 'pong'];
$TEST_ENDPOINT = '/ping';

function calcSig($body) {
  global $SANDBOX_API_SECRET, $method, $TEST_ENDPOINT;

  $mstime = floor(microtime(true) * 1000);
  $hmac = $mstime;
  $hmac .= $method;
  $hmac .= $TEST_ENDPOINT;

  $contentHash = md5(json_encode($body));
  $hmac .= $contentHash;

  $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $hmac, $SANDBOX_API_SECRET);

  $auth = 'HMAC ' . $mstime . ':' . $hmac;
  return $auth;
}

$headers = [
  'authorization' => calcSig($body),
  'api-key' => '_U6-ALTe5WWETJdHn8RxIQjUZI-pKW0lmfSTzYPrOhU=',
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
];

echo print_r($headers);
try {
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'ping', [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'json' => $body
    ]);    
    echo $response->getBody();
} catch (ClientException $e) {
    echo Psr7\Message::toString($e->getRequest());
    echo Psr7\Message::toString($e->getResponse());
}
   
} else {
   // Return error if you access directly
   echo 'No access';
}
?>
```

Link to reference of API Rest of Striga:
https://docs.striga.com/reference/create-user

I have tried to change the header by generating an HMAC from scratch, I have also tried to generate different json in various formats, but I can't get it to return a message in status 200 again. It just pops up error 401 or 400.

Comment: See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. Also please don't assume that we know anything about this specific API. Please provide a link to the relevant documentation of the endpoint you are trying to access, so we are able to understand what that endpoint requires you to send.

Comment: Also, [English is required for all content on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). Please translate everything in your post into English. You can use the [edit] button to change it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I translated all my content and I add code of errors. Thanks in advance all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client makes a request to `base_uri + endpoint`.

In the example from their documentation, they use `https://www.sandbox.striga.com/api/v1/` as the base URI, so in combination with endpoint `ping`, that will result in a POST request to `https://www.sandbox.striga.com/api/v1/ping`.

*You* used `https://www.sandbox.striga.com/api/v1/user/create` as the base URL, which in combination with `ping` will result in `https://www.sandbox.striga.com/api/v1/user/createping`.

The endpoint is part of the value that gets hashed. Your hash still contains `/ping` in that position, whereas the value they will be using on their end to calculate the hash for comparison, is `/user/createping` (because that is the part after the base_uri, and the only information they have available at this point, as to what endpoint your wanted to target.)

So of course theses two hashes don't match now.

If you want to make a request to that user creation endpoint - then you need to *keep* the `base_uri` as `https://www.sandbox.striga.com/api/v1/`, and set `$TEST_ENDPOINT = '/user/create'`;

And also make it `$client->request('POST', 'user/create'` in the part where you make the actual request then.

Comment: The discrepancy in their example, that `$TEST_ENDPOINT = '/ping';` contains the leading slash, but the value used in the Guzzle arguments is just `ping` hardcoded, is a bit ... unlucky, IMHO. It would make more sense, if they either defined their base_uri without the trailing slash, so that in the Guzzle arguments `$TEST_ENDPOINT` could be used directly then; or made that part use `ltrim($TEST_ENDPOINT, '/')` instead.

Comment: Buuff, I was stuck for a whole day and I see that it was just a parameter error, I really appreciate it. Now the problem is that the page does not find a 404 type error. I do not know if the error is because it is a post page can not give information as such or there is simply some parameter that does not fit at all. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Now appear this error before 404 <h1> by echo in php HTTP/1. 1 404 Not Found Date: Thu, 21 Sep 2023 13:43:06 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Connection: close x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block x-content-type-options: nosniff referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade content-security-policy: default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors 'self'; permissions-policy: interest-cohort=() strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC Server: cloudflare CF-RAY: 80a2bc3678b00632-IAD alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400

Comment: Not sure what exactly _"before 404 <h1> by echo in php"_ is supposed to mean, can't even tell if you are referring to a 404 return _from_ the API here, or if you are  getting one from your own system. But either way, that rather sounds like a new problem, which you should discuss in a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I have now published a post where I explain it better. Thank you very much for your answer, I gave it its corresponding point! :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77151830/error-404-in-the-middle-of-a-post-with-striga-what-is-the-reason